# Why are all of my footnotes hyperlinked to the titlepage?

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, back-referencing, footmisc

### Problem

I have various footnotes, which are hyperlinked from the text to the bottom of their respective pages. When I click on the hyperlinks (in the main text), they always take me to the first page of my document. I also have `footnotebackref` which puts a hyperlink *at* the footnote to take the reader back to the main body of text and these links for fine.

### Edited MWE

After a lot of deletion, I have managed to reduce the document to the following lines. One might say that I have found the problem, since the removal of `\usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}` stops the problem, but I would still like to have non-indented footnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}         %Problem line.
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents            
\newpage                
\section{Section}
This is some text\footnote{This is a footnote.}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. In that case, I will have to do without one or the other, or perhaps a workaround. P.s. if you want to add your comment as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In a comment to the question I quoted `footmisc`'s manual:

> The `hyperref` package has ambitions to make hyperlinks from footnote
>   marks to the corresponding footnote body; naturally this causes grief
>   to `footmisc`, and unfortunately no remedy is currently known. If you
>   use `footmisc`, suppress `hyperref`'s hyperfootnotes, by loading it as:
>   `\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,...]{hyperref}` Further work on the
>   interaction between the two packages is proposed, but not yet
>   scheduled.

So it is to be expected that things might not be working the way one wishes. However, the problems in the MWE can simply be solved by changing the package loading order:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents            
\newpage                
\section{Section}
This is some text\footnote{This is a footnote.}.

\newpage\null% to see that the hyperlink works
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that this issue is not still resolved. Changing the loading order works but some custom classes (in article templates etc) include `hyperref` so we do end up loading `footmisc` after `hyperref`.

Comment: @WYSIWYG for such cases package `scrlfile` from the KOMA-Script bundle may be useful…

Comment: @clemens, unfortunately, this workaround does not work with memoir. any suggestions?

Comment: Your workaround worked very nicely for my project report (with the `article` class), thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I would like to leave a tip for Brazilian users which for some documents must use the regional standard package `abntex2cite`. I hope this tip may also be helpful to solve other issues with `hyperref` as well.

The package `hyperref` should be the last loaded package, but it is not always the case as said in: [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before).

The package `abntex2cite` is one of those exceptions and must be loaded after `hyperref`.

The problem is: if you load `hyperref` after `abntex2cite`, the `.bbl` file will have errors and the references won't be properly written. And the references are the (main) reason to use `abntex2cite`. Therefore `hyperref` must come before `abntex2cite`.

But this leads to another problem. The links to footnotes will lead to the first page. To correct this issue, it is necessary to load the package `setspace` before `hyperref.

A MWE is given below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace} % Always before hyperref -- Enable correct footnote link
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}   % Normas ABNT - After hyperref
\begin{document}
First Page.

With the package setspace before hyperref, the footnotes work properly.

Without the package setspace or if it is loaded after hyperref, the footnotes don't work properly.

\clearpage
This is the first footnote\footnote{Text 1.}.

\clearpage
This is the second footnote\footnote{Text 2.}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

For those using the apacite, babel and hyperef packages, this might work.

I loaded first all the other packages, then hyperref, then babel, then apacite.

```
% Load the rest of your packages here then use the order
    \usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true,colorlinks]{hyperref}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage{apacite} 
\begin{document}
```

Comment: This really helped me, though I do not use apacite: changing the order of loaded packages by putting {hyperref} after {footmisc} solved my problem.