# \footnote reference doesn't jump to correct page

Tags: footnotes

I have a footnote, and when I click the reference link in PDF, it jumps to the start of the document. It never shows up the page where the footnote is or should be.

[image: 1]

code:

```
\footnote{\label{foot_note1}The above equations assumes the terms (2 NA) should be replaced by ${\text{NA}_{\text{condenser}}+\text{NA}_{\text{obj}}}$}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. — Does the issue go away if you compile again?

Comment: MWE : https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=9B7D716405D76EE4!7491&authkey=!AEoEvS1Md7CWtrE

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel : The footnote is on Page 3 of the document when compiled  and clicking on it takes me to page 1. (I am not sure if its right way to provide a MWE, but since mine contains additional package to run, I had to share it this way.) Thanks.

Comment: Found similar problem here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71664/why-are-all-of-my-footnotes-hyperlinked-to-the-titlepage