# How to suppress ALL hyperfootnotes; not just the first

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, footmisc

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71664/why-are-all-of-my-footnotes-hyperlinked-to-the-titlepage#answer-72691) the author points out a comment in the [`footmisc`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc) manual:

> The [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref) package has ambitions to make hyperlinks from footnote
>   marks to the corresponding footnote body; naturally this causes grief
>   to `footmisc`, and unfortunately no remedy is currently known. If you
>   use footmisc, **suppress hyperref's hyperfootnotes, by loading it as:
>   `\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,...]{hyperref}`** Further work on the
>   interaction between the two packages is proposed, but not yet
>   scheduled. (emphasis added)

And while I have indeed done that, it's not working as advertised.

Here's my (slightly revised, to test my assertion in the comment below) MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=cyan,hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
This is a worthwhile document.\footnote{\label{note1}Here is a \href{http://
www.wikipedia.org}{reference}.} Please have a look at it.

\lipsum[1-10] % to generate filler text.

And I'd like to draw your attention to the 
same document here\footref{note1}, here\footref{note1}, and here\footref
{note1} too.

Here is another good read.\footnote{\label{note2}Please see Title 17 USC \S 107.}

\lipsum[10-20] % to generate filler text.

And here\footref{note2} is a good place to refer to the second footnoted document.

\end{document}
```

This suppresses the first hyperfootnote, but the second (for both * and dagger footnote markers), third, and fourth (for * footnote markers) are still hyper-sensitive (so-to-speak). How do I make **all** of them non-hyper?

This is important because as I show in this revised example, when the reader clicks the second dagger footnote marker on page 6, the hypertext should (if the two packages played well together) take the reader back to page 3 (where the footnote for the dagger mark is typeset and where the first footnote marker appears in the text). But in fact, it takes the reader back to page 1, apparently referring the reader to the * footnote when the reader clicked on the dagger footnote mark. My solution would be to simply suppress all hyperness in the hyperfootnotes, but my problem with that is that suppressing it as described in the documentation causes suppression of hypertext in only the *first* footnote mark, not subsequent marks.

One comment below indicates that the footnote marks are still red, but not hyper. However that differs from my experience. Is that because I have the TeXlive 2011 version? I tried typesetting the MWE above using both LaTeX and XeLaTeX and in both cases, the second, third, and fourth footnote marks are both red and hypertext.

## EDIT

Thank you @Sverre for compiling with TeXLive 2013. Can anyone else confirm these results with different versions than 2011 and 2013? It's beginning to look like it's time for me to file a bug report.

I would still welcome any work-arounds.

Comment: In my computer is not "still sensitive", just "still red". The same behavior is obtained with `scrextend`.

Comment: I've compiled with pdfLaTeX in TeXlive2013, and I get the same as the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can patch `\footref{}` from footmisc. Insert the following lines after the `\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\footref}{\ref}{\ref*}{}{}
```

With this change, there are no coloured or hyperlinked footnotes from your example.

Answer (score 0):

Since this seem to be a bug (tested myself with up-to-date TeXLive 2013), you might use just this work around, as you've specified that

> my real goal is just to get the hyperfootnotes gone.

The `\url`-command will produce links in your PDF-file without the need for the `hyperref`-package. This doesn't allow to mask the reference easily, but you should think about your paper is a printed-out version. The link might still be useful then, although the text 'reference' is getting useless without a computer. The click-ability of the links produced by the command `\url` seems to be reader-dependent.

Your modified MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
This is a worthwhile document.\footnote{\label{note1}Here is a \url{http://
www.wikipedia.org}.} Please have a look at it.

\lipsum[1-10] % to generate filler text.

And I'd like to draw your attention to the 
same document here\footref{note1}, here\footref{note1}, and here\footref
{note1} too.

Here is another good read.\footnote{\label{note2}Please see Title 17 USC \S 107.}

\lipsum[10-20] % to generate filler text.

And here\footref{note2} is a good place to refer to the second footnoted document.

\end{document}
```