# (LyX) Disable footnote links

Tags: hyperref, lyx, footnotes

Similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71664/why-are-all-of-my-footnotes-hyperlinked-to-the-titlepage), I have the problem where the hyperref footnote link sends me back to the title page.

I'm trying to add "hyperfootnotes=false" as an option in the LyX > Document Settings > PDF Properties > Hyperlinks menu. But this doesn't seem to do anything. Am I doing it wrong?

[image]

Comment: If I recall correctly, you must use that option in the original call to `hyperref`: you can't put it in `\hypersetup` (so `\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}`, not `\usepackage{hyperref} \hypersetup{hyperfootnotes=false}`). Can you check to see how LyX uses `hyperref`?

Comment: Yes, @jon is right. One way to accomplish this in LyX is to go to Document > Settings and under "Class Options" put "hyperfootnotes=false". This will be picked up by hyperref. Assuming this works for Kenny, jon go ahead and put that as the answer.

Comment: @scottkosty -- Maybe you should answer it (if it is answered) since you can speak about LyX with some real authority. I'd really just be writing what you say on faith.

Comment: @jon I could almost say the same about LaTeX but it is true that I can at least test the solution. In any case, let's see if the proposed solution works for Kenny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to put "hyperfootnotes=false" under "Class Options" in Document > Settings.

The reason, as @jon points out in the comment above, is that the option must be passed for the original loading of hyperref (and not the subsequent `\hypersetup` command).